# i have an error in my background service and i'm using volley library

Tags: android-volley

12-21 16:36:20.522 24309-24309/islamicapp.com.ranatechnology.ww.tawfiiqislamiccenter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                       Process: islamicapp.com.ranatechnology.ww.tawfiiqislamiccenter, PID: 24309
                                                                                                       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (stack size 16384 bytes) failed: Try again
                                                                                                           at java.lang.VMThread.create(Native Method)
                                                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1029)
                                                                                                           at com.android.volley.RequestQueue.start(RequestQueue.java:152)
                                                                                                           at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:79)
                                                                                                           at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:105)
                                                                                                           at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:115)
                                                                                                           at islamicapp.com.ranatechnology.ww.Service.NotificationService.servicestart(NotificationService.java:139)
                                                                                                           at islamicapp.com.ranatechnology.ww.Service.NotificationService.onStartCommand(NotificationService.java:58)
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2712)
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:142)
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
                                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5120)
                                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
                                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
                                                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Please share code as well. just an error message is not Always that easy to use.

Comment: actually I'm new here and i dont know how post question anyway i'll try to post code